# How to write a nested condition using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a column named Ordered in a show page which prints Order number as :

```
<div class="col-sm-2 detail" ng-if="clTxn.ordered">
  <a ng-if="relTransaction.txnType == 'Order'" ng-repeat="relTransaction in clTxn.relTransactions" ui-sref="order({id: relTransaction.txnId })">{{'Ord#'}}</a>
  <div class="title">Ordered</div>
</div>
```

It is working fine with order, now I need to add the same when `relTransaction.txnType == 'Purchase'`.
I am new to angular but I tried to put the same above Order with Purchase but didn't worked for me.

Note both Order and Purchase must be under this condition:

`'ng-if' => 'clTxn.ordered'`

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post the entire template code?
Where did you put those conditions? In the attribute of a tag in your template?

I Don't understand

Comment: Actually Just I need to write an extra ng-if condition under **{'ng-if' => 'clTxn.ordered'}** for Purchase like `'ng-if' => "relTransaction.txnType == 'Order'` as shown in question.

Comment: Oh I see now, is it a HTML preprocessor?

Please write HTML instead for people that can't read it

Comment: edited to html from haml

Comment: can you show us a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-2 detail" ng-if="clTxn.ordered">
  <a ng-if="['Order', 'Purchase'].indexOf(relTransaction.txnType) != -1" ng-repeat="relTransaction in clTxn.relTransactions" ui-sref="order({id: relTransaction.txnId })">{{'Ord#'}}</a>
  <div class="title">Ordered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `ng-if="('Purchase' == relTransaction.txnType) || ('Order' == relTransaction.txnType)"`

Comment: Actually we have to show **"PO#"** if `'ng-if' => "relTransaction.txnType == 'Purchase'` and **"Ord#"** if `'ng-if' => "relTransaction.txnType == 'Order'`

Comment: Then there are 2 different blocks